# rails - how do i include view helpers in my tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, helper

I'm referencing helper items in my tests, how can I include the helpers so that they are available for tests?

Comment: I think this [article](http://alexjsharp.com/posts/testing-rails-view-helpers) will get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This blog has an excellent writeup on how to test view helpers.

[http://alexjsharp.com/posts/testing-rails-view-helpers](http://alexjsharp.com/testing-rails-view-helpers/)